# BASH: Recursive rename to last modification date prefix

Tags: bash, recursion, find, rename, mv

I have tried for an hour or two and I can't get this to work right. I'm trying to prefix a mass of files throughout a directory tree with the file's last modification date, in a specific %d%m%y format with a following dash (-). The filename needs to be windows compatible.

This works on one directory of course:

```
for f in *; do mv $f $(date -r $f + %d%m%y)-$f ; done;
```

Renaming logs like:
logfile-0001.txt to 030417-logfile-0001.txt

But I can't figure out how to do this recursively. My problem is either not being able to specify a $f for the date -r, OR I am returned filenames that start with ./ which is no help either and I'm sure there is an easier way than parsing each output to remove the ./ before using the remaining filename to then search for and rename.

The directory trees are somewhat numerous and files sit at different levels.

I have tried using find with -exec and -execdir etc but when I'm putting in "{}" into the date command it's out of the scope and date can't find the file.

Very frustrating. Hoping someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: I think I just did it with:

`for f in **/*.txt ; do mv $f ${f%/*}/$(date -r $f +%d%m%y)-${f##*/}  ; done ;`

Seemed to have a few problems but most of the work is done

Comment: Great! Could you post an answer to your own question and accept it? Thnx!